# Чтение Email почты на C#

Tags: c#, email

Посоветуйте библиотеку или классы по работе с email на C#. 
Интересует чтение почты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use google, Luke.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6062/A-POP3-Client-in-C-NET